# unexpected "None" in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wanted to make a game where you guess the letter. and add a function that will show you all you incorrect guesses, so i made the list:

```
incorrectguesses = []
```

and then i made it so it asks the user to guess the letter:

```
while True:
    guess = input("what do you think the letter is??  ")
    if guess == secret_letter:
        print("you guessed it!")
        break
    else:
        incorrectguesses += [guess]
```

and you can see that i added the guess to the list if it was wrong.

then, i added a function to print out every item in the given list:

```
def print_all_items(list_): 
    for x in list_: 
        print(x)
```

and then i ran the function at the end of the loop:

```
print(print_all_items(incorrectguesses))
```

but this was the result:

> what do you think the letter is??  a
>
> a
>
> None
>
> what do you think the letter is?? b
>
> a
>
> b
>
> None

as you can see, it adds "None" to the end of the list.

thanks if you could help me

Comment: You don't have `None` in the list. Your function does not have `return`, so the function is returning `None`. Then `print(print_all_items()...)` is simply printing `None`.

Comment: `print_all_items` doesn't return anything, so implicitly it returns `None` -- your code is then printing this `None`. If the point of `print_all_items` is to, well, print all items, then why are you trying to print those items again?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(print_all_items(incorrectguesses))
```

You're printing the *result* of the `print_all_items()` function.

However, that function has no `return` statement, so it returns `None` by default.

So, the *result* of the function is `None`, and that gets printed.

Since the function itself prints the results, I think you actually just want to *call* the function, not *print* its result.

Comment: Your avatar is absolutely lovely!

Comment: Thanks! yeah, i already printed it in my function so i did not have to print it again.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else pointed earlier (beat me to it), it's because you are printing a function that has no `return`. (In depth explanation a the end).

```
while True:
    guess = input("what do you think the letter is??  ")
if guess == secret_letter:
    print("you guessed it!")
    break
else:
    incorrectguesses += [guess]
    print_all_items(incorrectguesses) # ←
```

You want to call the function, not print it.

That way the function is being run, and prints the elements of `incorrectguesses`.

---

###### Explanation

When you do `print(<something>)`, the `print()` function is waiting for a value to be returned.

In this case because the `<something>` is a function, Python runs that function "inside" the `print()`. When your function `print_all_items()` is being run, it prints all the elements of the list. Once `print_all_items()` has finished running, and printed everything, the function doesn't return a value, so it defaults to `None`. Therefore, the value of the `<something>` the `print(<something>)` was waiting for is gets assigned a `None` value.

I hope I could help!